# Inserting only SELECTED fields in combo box into a Temp Table

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I've created a form that pulls in records and displays them in a List Box. I have a radio button for "all employees" where it selects them all and i can create a report but I also have a radio button for "select employees" so I can go in and select the few that I want to report on. The problem is when I select a few employees It still Loops through all  of the records in the list box while inputting into the temp table. Is there a simple way to quickly Insert just the selected items into the temp table?

any help would be appreciated even a link that sounds like it might help.

Comment: Post your attempted code. Are you using ItemsSelected property of listbox? Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-50.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through the `.ItemsSelected` and retrieve the selected item's value through `.ItemData(selectedItem)`:

```
Dim selectedItem As Variant

With Me.YourListBoxControlName  
    For Each selectedItem In .ItemsSelected
        MsgBox .ItemData(selectedItem) 
    Next
End With
```