# Is it possible to assign an Access listbox value to an output format on EmailDatabaseObject

Tags: database, forms, email, ms-access, listbox

As the title suggests, what I need to know is a way to get a listbox value which has an email address to appear in the CC section of the output format of an Emaildatabaseobject.

I've tried multiple ways now but the best I've had is the =[Forms]![Training_admin]![List54] show in the outlooks CC, rather than the actual result.

There is only one result within the query which is appearing in the listbox, but I just cannot get the value to the email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the multiselect property is 'None', this should do:

```
Forms.Training_admin.List54.Value
```

For multiselect, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43810958/inserting-only-selected-fields-in-combo-box-into-a-temp-table/43820493#43820493).